# Trouble in sending files in MQTT

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

I am new to MQTT. I was trying to explore how to send files with MQTT.

I tried to convert a picture (.jpg format) into a byte array. If I directly send the byte array as MQTT payload, it works well. But, I need to send the file information, so I tried to pack into a json object and send, but json only allows string. So, I tried to send the byte array as string.

```
file = "pic.jpg";
f = open (file, "rb");
fileContent = f.read();
byteArray = bytearray(fileContent);

fileData = {
    'name': file,
    'content': str(byteArray)
}
payload=json.dumps(fileData);

sender.publish(TOPIC, payload=payload, qos=2, retain=False);
```

Now, when I receive the byte array, I tried to encode the string content to byte array. But, I see, all the newline characters are not formatted correctly, and it does not produce the file.

```
def onMessage(client, userdata, msg):
    print("=> Message Received");

    fileData = json.loads(msg.payload)

    f = open(fileData['name'], "wb");
    f.write(bytes(fileData['content'], 'utf-8'));

    f.close();
```

Please help me understand the file data encoding and decoding techniques. Thank you!

Comment: I dont think a jpg is utf-8.

Comment: Try converting it to base64 before you dump it and decode the payload with utf8 to get the base64 string, then decode it.

Comment: I tried this and it works.. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

As you have correctly discovered, you can't send arbitrary binary data, such as an image, in a JSON.

One option might be to base64-encode the image and put that in a JSON with the image name and other meta-data. But, depending on your environment, you may be paying a heavy price because JPEGs are often 100-300kB and base64-encoding will always inflate that by 33%.

However, there is nothing to stop you sending two parts in one message. So, as a second option, you *could* send a JSON with the filename and metadata (ownership, dates) followed by the raw binary data. If you want to do that, you could decide to always send say a 4-byte header with the length of the JSON packet encoded in network byte order using `htonl()` so that the decoder knows how many bytes to strip off the start and interpret as JSON - and thereby to also know where the image starts.

A third option is to leverage the fact that both JPEGs and PNG images have a well-known sequence of bytes both at the start and end, so you could either append or prepend an image to a JSON and find the boundary between the two by searching using a regex within a message. Check the Wikipedia entries for PNG and JPEG:

- JPEG start = `ff d8 ff`
- JPEG end = `ff d9`
- PNG start = `89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a`
- PNG end = `49 45 4e 44 ae 42 60 82`

My preference would normally tend to be the second option, but all 3 should work.

Comment: These are very useful information.. I would try those. Thank you :)